# Returning multiple strings using XPATH

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Source website is here on [Nethys](https://aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?Class=Shaman)

Since I don't know all of the terminologies I'm going to keep this as neutral as possible. I'm trying to gather information from this website into separate columns in a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gqeXbz3YcCucpCllhRsacPyCvjf8TRTG9Ge4aIOFLPs/edit?usp=sharing). 
I want the bold text in one column, the associated link in the next, and the spell description in another. The issue comes when a description references another spell they put it in italics which breaks the description into multiple parts seen in `C153` and `C154`. I think it would be easier to just grab everything in between the bold text and a line break but I don't know the context.

From an example such as (Forgive me if the formatting is wrong, I'm mostly guessing here);

```
<p>
 <b>
  <a href='link1'> 
  Bold Link 1
  </a>
 </b>
 :Followed by normal text
 <br>
 <b>
  <a href='link2'>
  Bold Link 2
  </a>
 </b>
 :Normal Text
 <i>with an italic</i>
 in between
 <br>
 <b>
  <a href='link3'>
  Bold Link 3
  </a>
 </b>
 :Back to this one
 <br>
</p>
```

I can get it to return
`:Followed by normal text`
`Normal text`
`in between`
`:Back to this one`

But I want it to return `:Followed by normal text` `:Normal text with an italic in between` `:Back to this one`

I don't even know if it's possible to do with a single command but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this already resolved?

Comment: @player0, no not even remotely. It actually got to the point where the limitations imposed by `IMPORTXML()` were so restrictive that on the advice of some other forums I just moved the whole project into Python via BS4. It was literally going to be easier to start from scratch than figure this out.

Comment: to avoid `IMPORTXML` limits it's better to import it just once and then scrape it across the cells. `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML("https://aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?Class=Shaman","//*"),10000,30)`

Comment: the catch is for all the iterations I was looking at doing it was going to require hundreds of `importXML`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select every text node descendant of `p` root element that it's not also descendant of `a` you could use this XPath:

```
/p//text()[not(ancestor::a)]
```

Or more restricted ussing the Kayian method:

```
/p//text()[count(.|/p//a//text()) != count(/p//a//text())]
```

**Note**: XPath 1.0 has no intersection nor set differenciation operators, but it has union by `|` operator and cardinality by `count()` function. [Dr. Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) discovered that those were enough to test for set membership: `a` element is member of `B` set if and only if {`a`} union `B` has the same cardinality than `B`. From there you build all the others set operations.